# @EnableAsync vs AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer#isAsyncSupported()

Tags: spring-mvc

I am too much confused the difference between `@EnableAsync` and `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer#isAsyncSupported()`.

As per this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-container-config),

> The isAsyncSupported protected method of AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer provides a single place to enable async support on the DispatcherServlet and all filters mapped to it. By default this flag is set to true

Based on my knowledge `@EnableAsync` is to enable scan `@Async` annotations and provide multi-threading support. But still I am unable to understand when to use `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer#isAsyncSupported()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a big difference between the two, `@EnableAsync` with `@Async` are not concerned with spring-web-mvc, they allow the execution of a method asynchronously  using a `TaskExecutor`. For example, if you had a clean up service that deletes all logs in a server, you can allow its doCleanUp method to run asynchronously without having to write the scheduling code, spring will take care of it for you:

```
public class CleanUpService {

     @Async
     public void doCleanUp() {
         // This code will be executed using a different thread than the calling thread by a TaskExecuter
     }
}
```

As you can see this is not related to web development in particular. Also note that this method returns void, but if you wanted it to return a result, for instance `CleanupStatistics`, you can't just write the method like this

```
 @Async
 public CleanupStatistics doCleanUp() {
     // This code will be executed using a different thread than the calling thread by a TaskExecuter
     return new CleanupStatistics("someinformation");
 }
```

You are [required](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) to return either `void` or a `Future`. A `Future` represents the result of an asynchronous computation that you can use to obtain the result of the computation when it becomes available. We will get back to `Future` and see how it can be used in controller methods while  `isAsyncSupported` is true.

isAsyncSupported is a totally different story, this flag enables Servlet 3.0 asynchronous request processing, prior to Servlet 3.0 a servlet container (Tomcat for instance) would have a thread pool that handles the processing of Http requests, each thread would handle the request till the processing is complete, even if the thread had to stay idle, for example, to wait for a database query to finish or for an API call result to come back. This affects the scalability of the servlet container. In Servlet 3.0 requests can be handled asynchronously, the container thread will call your handler method, in its turn the handler method can schedule its work to be done asynchronously and return immediately, freeing the container thread to process other requests, after the result is available any container thread can resume the processing of the request. From the prospective of the client, nothing has changed, the client, all that time, is still waiting for the result to come back, but from the perspective of the server, the container threads are better utilised.

In spring-mvc you can trigger asynchronous request processing for a controller method by returning certain java types, for example

- `DeferredResult`
- `Callable`
- `ListenableFuture`
- `CompletionStage`
- `CompletableFuture`
- Reactive types
- and streaming types

If you wanted to use @Async with isAsyncSupported you could write a controller method that calls a method annotated with @Async and returns `ListenableFuture`.

You can learn more about task execution and scheduling [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html). And more about Servlet 3.0 asynch [here](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support).

Comment: Yazan, you rock my world! (want to upvote this thread until I accept this answer. Since this is my first thread, I'm unable to do so, apologies). I've to read about Servlet 3.x asynchronous support.

Comment: So in order to use EnableAsync annotation, the value of isAsyncSupported method should be true. In other words, if I override isAsyncSupported method and make it false, 
then even though if I am annotating my component class with @EnableAsync, it's of no use. Isn't it?

Comment: Glad to help, you probably mean Async in the above comment, EnableAsync is a configuration that enables spring asynchronous execution (through Async and other means), while Async is what marks a method to be executed asynchronously. Even if your if isAsyncSupported is false you can annotate methods with Async but you will not get correct results if a controller method is annotated with Async

Answer (score 0):

If we want to experience benefits provided by Spring MVC and don't want to manually register DispatcherServlet it'll be better to use: **AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer**. It adds two abstract methods: createServletApplicationContext() and getServletMappings().
First method returns WebApplicationContext that will be passed to DispatcherServlet, which will be automatically added into container ServletContext. This context will be established as a child of the context returned by createRootApplicationContext() method. Second method -returns mappings that are used during servlet registration.

The **@EnableAsync** annotation switches on Spring’s ability to run @Async methods in a background thread pool. For Enabling asynchronous processing with Java configuration got by simply adding the @EnableAsync to a configuration class.

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class SpringAsyncConfigurer implements AsyncConfigurer {...}
```

@Async is applicable only to the public methods.
Calling the @Async method within the same class woould not work.